# What are all the resources of an old VM I should consider when mirroring to the new VM? (description)

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, mirror

I am tasked with setting up a new VM that mirrors an old VM. The challenge is that I cannot use snapshots.

I have listed packages from the old VM to install on the new. And I have ensured the OS versions are in sync. Assuming the hardware is already verified, what else should I consider?

Let me know if I can add more detail to this question.

Comment: Config files, crontabs, users, network configuration, passwords, ... What do you mean by "mirror" if not "clone the harddrive"?

Comment: @Panki - This is exactly what I'm looking for. Let me know if there are more items I can check. By mirror, I did mean cloning, but for this practice, I am doing everything manually.